# Configure Rider to debug .Net and Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, debugging, rider

I struggle with Rider configuration. I created a .Net project with Angular - when I start the debug, I hit only the .Net breakpoints. Exactly what should I do so I can debug typescript and .Net at the same time?

This is how my debug configuration looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to start the Angular server so that it compiles the app:
[image]

The next step is to configure the Angular app itself so that the browser will start:
[image]

Now start *Angular CLI Server*, wait some seconds so that the app gets compiled, and then run *Angular App*.

Since I'm a lazy guy, I automated this step as well:
[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nice, this is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks! :))
This Multirun template comes from a plugin? 
Just out of curiosity - I figured out I can pass another configuration to "Before launch". So instead of Multirun with delay,  is it a viable solution to configure this behavior through "before launch"?

Comment: Yeah exactly, that's the Multirun plugin

Comment: Unfortunately multirun ddint solve it for me, running Cli Task in Debug mode just causes it to hang. And you cannot run it as 'Before Launch' coz that will never finish